# Using an uninitialized global variable (for read and write) is OK?

Tags: c, variables, initialization, global-variables

If I use uninitialized global variable in C program, What happens? Is it undefined behavior?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i;

int main() 
{
    while(i < 5)
    {
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Global variables will be initialized with 0 if there is no explicit initialization.

Comment: What did you search/ re-search?

Comment: As per Standard C compiler, which initialize global variable to zero by default, if not defined.at compilation

Comment: @Jayesh, Read a good book.  https://www.udemy.com/c-programming-for-beginners/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** No, you're fine.

But don't take my word for it, let's also see a bit more on the *why* part, following the authoritative sources.

First of all, let's see the scopes of the identifiers (variable).

<sub>*Note:all emphasis mine*</sub>

As per `C11`, chapter §6.2.1

> If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier
>   **appears outside of any block or list of parameters, the identifier has file scope**, which
>   terminates at the end of the translation unit.

Then, from chapter §6.2.2

> [...] If
>   the declaration of an identifier for an object has **file scope and no storage-class specifier,
>   its linkage is external**.

and, finally, for the storage class, chapter §6.2.4,

> An object whose identifier is declared **without the storage-class specifier
>   `_Thread_local`, and either with external or internal linkage** or with the storage-class
>   specifier `static`, **has static storage duration**.

So,  the *global* variable you mentioned has static storage duration.

Now, you say, it is not initialized explicitly, lets see what the spec has to say about this.

Quoting chapter §6.7.9/P10,

> If **an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then**:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — **if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;**
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>   and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>   rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

So, the variable has a *defined value* even without explicit initialization, so using that variable to *read* is perfectly OK. ***No undefined behavior here.***

Answer (score 6):

> Is it undefined behavior?

No.

> What happens?

`i` has static storage duration (file scope). It will initialize to zero by default.